# No such property: usedPackageDeps

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I use ext-6.5.1 (CMD 6.5.1.240) and changed my app.json to the following:

Code:

```
"production": {
    "output": {
        ...
        "js": {
             "filter": "used"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.5.0/guides/whats_new_cmd.html

After running

```
sencha app build production
```

I got this error:

```
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: No such property : usedPackagesDeps
```

Any clue why this does occur and how to fix? The doc's aren't helping much.

Comment: The entire questions is copied from the Sencha forum, including the broken link. Are you having the exact same problem after 4 years?
https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?363334-BUILD-No-such-property-usedPackageDeps

Comment: yes, same problem. No answers. This issue still exists in latest version of sencha CMD

Comment: I wrote to sencha support and they replayed that there is a bug in sencha cmd.